How can I use the --domain parameter when trying to run rasa tests in github actions?
I have this gate.yml file in my .github workflows directory that should test the model every time a pull request on the master branch is created.
name: Rasa 

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  training-testing:
    name: Training and Testing
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Rasa Train and Test GitHub Action
        uses: RasaHQ/rasa-train-test-gha@main
        with:
          data_validate: true
          rasa_train: true
          cross_validation: true
          rasa_test: true
          test_type: all
          publish_summary: true
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Upload model
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: model
          path: models

Now everytime I create a pull-request I get the following error:

I'm not entirely sure if it has to do with my directory structure, but that's where both files are located:
.github
-workflows
--gate.yml
stockrecolib
-chatbot
--domain.yml


From the implementation, looks like that action provides this via its *_args input parameters. For example, for rasa train command, you can pass it like this train_args: '--domain path/to/domain'. For other stages, you need to configure it accordingly for their respective _args input param.

BTW, you should use actions/checkout@v4.

I tried it with train_args and test_nlu_args the following way (with and without apostrophe) => '--domain stockrecolib/chatbot/domain.yml' and it still gives me the same error.

Try adding it in data_validate_args as well.
